# Python lambda - too much optimized

Tags: python, lambda

the following code:

```
tab = [lambda: elt for elt in [1,2,3,4,5]]
for elt in tab:
        print(elt())
```

gives the following output:

```
➜  ~ python code.py
5
5
5
5
5
```

Is there any way to switch off (or weaken) this optimisation?

Comment: Also find this additional [blog post](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) which I find it useful to understand what's happening here.

Comment: It's not an optimisation; it's just the way Python variables work.

Comment: This definition of tab produces the desired output: `tab = [lambda x=elt: x for elt in [1,2,3,4,5]]` (i.e. lambda function with default argument).  This way we get a closure on each of the values  as desired.

Comment: ok, thanks all clear now!